# .jar missing in deployed JBoss .war

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, jboss, war

I know this has been asked a few times in the past, but I'm unable to find a solution (except for the "add the .jar to your project manually in Eclipse"..)

What I have:

- A Maven project
- A .jar web-service we've created (let's call it `kc.ourwebservice`)

After a *`clean install`* (in Eclipse or via the command line) and *Full Publish* in Eclipse (and yes, I have done an *Update Maven Project - Force Update of Snapshots/Releases* before that), this `.jar` can be found in:

- This kc.ourwebservice.jar is present in our Nexus Repository Manager OSS
- This kc.ourwebservice.jar is present in our Eclipse project at the Maven dependencies
- This kc.ourwebservice.jar is present when I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`
- This kc.ourwebservice.jar is present in my `.m2` folder

However, it's missing from the deployed JBoss `.war`'s `lib` folder, which is what my question is about.

I know I could manually add the `.jar` in Eclipse' *Deployment Assembly* (or `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file), but every time I switch git branches or do an "*Update Maven Project*", it's gone again. And I also don't want to manually add this `.jar` when the project is put on a server.
I need a permanent solution so the `.jar` is correctly added to the deployed JBoss `.war`, using the Maven plugins that were designed for it.

One thing to add. This webservice has both an `.aar` and `.jar`. Both of them are necessary. The `.jar` when we're starting the application, so I gave it a `<scope>compile</scope>`, and all the `.aar` we use are only needed at runtime, so I gave it that scope (`<scope>runtime</scope>`).

Here is the relevant `pom.xml` code (lots of more dependencies, plugins and code at the `...`'s, but those are irrelevant for this problem):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    ...
  </parent>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
  <properties>
    ...
    <ourwebservice.version>1.0.0</ourwebservice.version>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <!-- Takes care of copying the aar services to the WEB-INF/services -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2-repo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</outputDirectory>
        <stripServiceVersion>false</stripServiceVersion>
        <services>...,ourwebservice</services>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <id>deploy webservices</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>create-repository</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${warOutputDir}</outputDirectory>
        <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
        <!-- Tell the maven war plugin to use the merged web.xml -->
        <webXml>${warOutputDir}/web.xml</webXml>
        <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
              <exclude>sample-properties.properties</exclude>
              <exclude>sample-log4j.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
          <!-- Copy the generated services that were extracted from the dependencies to the WEB-INF/services folder of the war archive. -->
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/services</directory>
            <targetPath>/WEB-INF/services</targetPath>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.aar</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
          ...
        </webResources>
        <!-- The axis2 services should not be stored in the WEB-INF/lib -->
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.aar</packagingExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <!-- JBoss plugin used to deploy war file - http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/ -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <hostName>${deploymentHostName}</hostName>
        <port>${deploymentPort}</port>
        <fileName>${deploymentFileName}</fileName>
        <serverName>default</serverName>
        <jbossHome>
          //${deploymentHostName}/${jbossHome}
        </jbossHome>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>kc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ourwebservice</artifactId>
      <version>${ourwebservice.version}</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>kc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ourwebservice</artifactId>
      <version>${ourwebservice.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Does anyone has any idea why the `.jar` isn't deployed to the `.war`? Or better yet, does anyone know a solution so the `.jar` is always deployed to this `.war` when doing a clean install and publish?

All other `.jar` files are present in the `.war`, this webservice is the only one missing.